# Replace elements of a table by other elements of the same table

Tags: recursion

I want to replace elements of a table by other elements of the same table which finally leads to an updated table.

```
Do[ a[i] = i, {i, 1, 5}]
Do[ a[i + 1] := a[i], {i, 1, 4}]
```

gives errors (assuming this is what I wanted to do, I expect an output such as {1,1,1,1,1}).

Comment: Note , lists need double brackets, what you define are functions. The you do not need a loop to set all elements of a list to a given value. E.g.: a = Range[5];
a[[All]] = a[[1]];
a

Comment: That was just an example. Suppose I want to swap item 2 with item 3 and update the list?

Comment: a[[{3, 2}]] = a[[{2, 3}]]

Comment: @Daniel Huber I got this error Set::noval: Symbol a in part assignment does not have an immediate value.

Comment: I can only guess, but the error message seems to indicate, that the array a does not yet  exist. E.g. you can not set a[[1]]=5 without having previously defined a by e.g. a={1,2,3}

Comment: a := {{2, 8}, {2, 10}, {1, 9}, {1, 9}, {5, 9}, {2, 10}, {1, 9}, {1, 
   7}, {4, 6}, {5, 6}}

Comment: a[[{3, 5}]] = a[[{5, 3}]]

Comment: Set::noval: Symbol a in part assignment does not have an immediate value.

Comment: You must not use delayed assignment `:=`but  `= `

Answer (score 4):

You are not generating a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) but rather assigning values to an indexed variable.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Do[a[i] = i, {i, 1, 5}]
```

[`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) does not produce an output. You need to look at the values of the indexed variable.

```
a /@ Range[5]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

In the second expression, use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)

```
Do[a[i + 1] = a[i], {i, 1, 4}]
```

The values are then

```
a /@ Range[5]

(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

If you want `a` to be a list,

```
Clear[a]

a = Table[i, {i, 1, 5}]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

or more simply,

```
a = Range[5]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)

Do[a[[i + 1]] = a[[i]], {i, 1, 4}]

a

(* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your list:

```
a = Range[5]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

Try this:

```
Drop[RotateLeft[a], -1]

(*  {2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

Have fun!